# Definite integral against a weight function

Tags: real-analysis

Given $a <c <b$, define $\alpha:[a,b]\to \Bbb R$ as follows: $\alpha(a)<\alpha(b)$,   $\alpha(c)\in \big[\alpha(a),\alpha(b)\big]$, and also

$$\alpha(x)=\begin{cases}
\alpha(a),&\text{if }a\le x<c\\
\alpha(b),&\text{if }c<x\le b\;.
\end{cases}$$

Let $f:[a,b]\to\Bbb R$ continuous.

Prove that $f\in R(\alpha)$ and that

$$\int_a^bf(x) d\alpha(x)=f(c)\big[\alpha(b)-\alpha(a)\big]$$

My attempt

Since $f$ is continuous on $[a, b]$ then $ f \in R (\alpha) $ on $[a,b]$

Then for a partition $P$ such that

$a=x_{0}<x_{1}<...<x_{i-1}=c<x_{i}<...<x_{n}=b$

We have

$U(P,f,\alpha)=M_{i}\big(\alpha(b)-\alpha(a)\big)$   and     $L(P,f,\alpha)=m_{i}\big(\alpha(b)-\alpha(a)\big)$

Can anyone help me to conclude the result please?

Thanks for your help

Comment: I have edited in a more informative title. I'm not certain I've captured the essence of the question. I encourage improvements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a Riemann-Stieltjes integral, so I would approach the problem in the following way:

As you mention, since $f$ is continuous, $f\in R(\alpha)$, thus, for a partition $\Gamma=\{a=x_0<x_1<\cdots<c<\cdots<x_n=b\}$, we have $$\int_a^b fd\alpha=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n M_i[\alpha(x_i)-\alpha(x_{i-1})].$$ Now, since we're told the only place where $\alpha(x_i)-\alpha(x_{i-1})\neq0$ is when $x_i=c$ or $x_{i-1}=c$, we're left with $$\int_a^bfd\alpha=M_{k}(\alpha(c)-\alpha(x_{k-1}))+M_{k+1}(\alpha(x_{k+1})-\alpha(c)).$$ Recalling that for $x<c$ we have $\alpha(x)=\alpha(a)$ and similarly for $\alpha(b)$, we have $$M_k\alpha(b)-M_{k+1}\alpha(a)+\alpha(c)(M_{k+1}-M_k).$$ Now, by the continuity of $f$, we have the $M_k$ and $M_{k+1}\to f(c)$ which implies the second term converges to $0$. Thus we have the result.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** So $\alpha$ is a step function that takes on two values and is discontinuous at $c$. This tells you that given a partition $P=\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$, most of the terms $\alpha(x_i)-\alpha(x_{i-1})=0$. The only time this doesn't happen is near $c$. This means the upper and lower sums will be very simple to write.

There are two cases: (1) $c \in P$, say $x_k=c$ for some $k$, and (2) $c \notin P$, say $x_{k-1}<c<x_k$ for some $k$. Find the upper and lower sums in each case, then compare their respective infimum and supremum.